# How do I make a toggle switch trigger a select dropdown to randomize its option value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, random, drop-down-menu

I'm setting up a page for a character generator, and I'm giving users the option to either randomize traits or enter their own. I have the "choice vs random" options set up as toggle switches for each trait category, and then if they want to choose their own, I have drop-down select menus for each category with all the traits listed.

Here's my HTML for the switches:

```
<div class="switch">
            <p>Class</p>
            <label>
              My Choice
              <input type="checkbox" id="class-choice">
              <span class="lever red darken-4"></span>
              Random
            </label>
          </div>
```

Here's my HTML for the corresponding select menu:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
            <select id="classMenu" name="class">
                <option value="barbarian">Barbarian</option>
                <option value="bard">Bard</option>
                <option value="cleric">Cleric</option>
                <option value="druid">Druid</option>
                <option value="fighter">Fighter</option>
                <option value="monk">Monk</option>
                <option value="paladin">Paladin</option>
                <option value="ranger">Ranger</option>
                <option value="rogue">Rogue</option>
                <option value="sorcerer">Sorcerer</option>
                <option value="warlock">Warlock</option>
                <option value="wizard">Wizard</option>
            </select>
            <label for="class">Class</label>
          </div>
```

What I want to have happen is that every time they click the toggle switch to "random," the corresponding drop-down menu will display a randomized option from the list. I have all the option names saved as an array in my JavaScript:

```
var charClasses = ["barbarian", "bard", "cleric", "druid", "fighter", "monk", "paladin", "ranger", "rogue", "sorcerer", "warlock", "wizard"];
```

I know I need to use some sort of event listener and a math randomizing function and then something to display that option value, but I guess I'm confused about how to actually do that. And then I think I'll have to use a $('#save-btn').on("click", ... to save it to localStorage as well. I just started learning JS and it's not really intuitive for me yet, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to write it for me, I just wanted some guidance from a more experienced coder because I only started teaching myself this a few weeks ago. I think I know the things I need to use, but I don't know how to use them. I'm autistic and have trouble applying things in a situation that's different from how I was first taught to use them (i.e. the basic examples given in books/online vs this very specific practical application). It's a steep learning curve, so please don't be patronizing :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a random item of array use:

```
var item = charClasses[Math.floor(Math.random()*charClasses.length)];
```

To select the item use:

```
$('#classMenu').val("item ");
```

You can use a button event like this:

```
$('#btnRandom').click(function() {
  var item = charClasses[Math.floor(Math.random()*charClasses.length)];
  $('#classMenu').val(item);
});
```

The code select a random value from array and put in variable item. Next select the item in select field.

Comment: "item " is looking for a STRING value of "item " not the value of the variable **item**. And if its a toggle, that suggests that in if statement needs to get the value to determine if they are selecting random.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to correct the quotes